# Check current CPU load in mongo via a driver?

Tags: mongodb

Been recently checking Grafana dashboards where you can see CPU loads across shards and was wondering... Can this be done programmatically?

I recall that using `mongotop` an stat regarding CPU load was retrieved, but not sure if via the driver that's something feasible to capture and react in consequence?

If it has to be done without the API, which would be the easiest solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find a metric that the server exposes, you can use the driver to query for it.

For metrics, try https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.serverStatus/ and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.stats/.

I suspect any decent monitoring solution would query the *system* (as in operating system) for things like CPU usage rather than a MongoDB process, since CPU usage is in fact a global metric.